# mapping two json based on ID value in python

Tags: python, json, api, dictionary, lookup

I have two jsons as follows:
json1:This is the payload I am submitting to an API

```
    {
        "id": 0,
        "object_type": "SCHEMA",
        "object_meta": {
            "source_id": 1002,
            "database": "raw_exadata",
            "schema": "clv"
                       },
        "business_name": "",
        "business_logic": "",
        "verified_use_cases": ["p"],
        "classifications": ["bb464f04-f879-361c-95e5-42bcca6a9535"]
    }
,
    {
        "id": 1,
        "object_type": "TABLE",
        "object_meta": {
            "source_id": 1002,
            "database": "raw",
            "schema": "clv",
            "table": "clv_cust"
                       },
       
        "business_name": "",
        "business_logic": "",
        "verified_use_cases": [],
        "classifications": ["p"],
       
    }
]
```

json2: this is the response of an API call which tells me the error in the data that was posted

```
{
   "errors": {
      "0": {
         "verified_use_cases": {
            "0": [
               "Not a valid UUID."
            ]
         }
      },
      "1": {
         "classifications": {
            "0": [
               "Not a valid UUID."
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I want to produce a very user friendly response to the posted payload stating such and such an object has an invalid entry hence it has failed.

For the above, I need to map (or lookup) on the "id" from json2 to json1 and fetch the object_type and also that the entry in the verified_use_cases, classifications is wrong with corresponding id.

What I have tried so far:

```
from collections import defaultdict

p=json.loads(response.text)
result=defaultdict(list)
for i in p['errors']:
    result['obj_id'].append(int(i))
    result['error'].append(p['errors'][i])
```

Now this gives me the object_id, but I am not sure how I can map it further with json1.

Kindly help.

PS: the fields, verified use cases, classifications are all multi valued with comma separated actually, hence you can see the "0" int the error json

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
json1 = [{
        "id": 0,
        "object_type": "SCHEMA",
        "object_meta": {
            "source_id": 1002,
            "database": "raw_exadata",
            "schema": "clv"
                       },
        "business_name": "",
        "business_logic": "",
        "verified_use_cases": ["p"],
        "classifications": ["bb464f04-f879-361c-95e5-42bcca6a9535"]
    }
,
    {
        "id": 1,
        "object_type": "TABLE",
        "object_meta": {
            "source_id": 1002,
            "database": "raw",
            "schema": "clv",
            "table": "clv_cust"
                       },
       
        "business_name": "",
        "business_logic": "",
        "verified_use_cases": [],
        "classifications": ["p"],
       
    }
]

json2 = {
   "errors": {
      "0": {
         "verified_use_cases": {
            "0": [
               "Not a valid UUID."
            ]
         }
      },
      "1": {
         "classifications": {
            "0": [
               "Not a valid UUID."
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}

resp = {}

for record in json1:
    key = str(record["id"])
    if key in json2["errors"]:
        record['errors'] = json2["errors"][key]#adding json2
        resp[key] = record
```

Response

```
print(json.dumps(resp))
    {
        "0": {
            "id": 0,
            "object_type": "SCHEMA",
            "object_meta": {
                "source_id": 1002,
                "database": "raw_exadata",
                "schema": "clv"
            },
            "business_name": "",
            "business_logic": "",
            "verified_use_cases ": ["p "],
            "classifications ": ["bb464f04 - f879 - 361 c - 95e5 - 42 bcca6a9535 "],
            "errors ": {
                "verified_use_cases ": {
                    "0 ": ["Not a valid UUID."]
                }
            }
        },
        "1 ": {
            "id ": 1,
            "object_type ": "TABLE ",
            "object_meta ": {
                "source_id ": 1002,
                "database ": "raw ",
                "schema ": "clv ",
                "table ": "clv_cust "
            },
            "business_name ": "",
            "business_logic ": "",
            "verified_use_cases ": [],
            "classifications": ["p"],
            "errors": {
                "classifications": {
                    "0": ["Not a valid UUID."]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider a couple of things in mind:

1. When you are working with APIs, make sure that you use some kind of validation or preprocesses, I suggest you to use `Pydantic` with it's validators and easiest ways of converting any json to necessary class.
2. Example of using `pydantic` with your code, example will be below.
3. Taking look at docs, here it is: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/

And as a result when you'd like to create any of these defined classes you can do:

```
parse_obj_as(ApiObject, response.json)
```

Example:

```
class ApiObject(BaseModel):
    id: int = Field(alias="id")
    object_type: str = Field(alias="object_type")
    object_meta: ObjectMeta = Field(alias="object_meta")  # Same class with it's defined fields
    business_name: str = Field(alias="business_name")
    business_logic: str = Field(alias="business_logic")
    verified_use_cases: List[str] = Field(alias="verified_use_cases")
    classifications: List[str] = Field(alias="classification")
```

Hm here's the how would I do this:

```
# dict {0: json[0], 1: json[1]}
json_map = {str(json.get("id", 0)): json for json in json1}
for key, value in json2.get("errors").items():
    if key in json_map:
        upd_json = json_map.get(key)
        upd_json["errors"] = value
        print(f"JSON with id {key} were updated")  # Just some logging that it was really updated
```

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot for this! but the API isn't created by me, I am just a end user though tbh :/

Comment: Doesn't matter, you can create such kind of class in your own files and parse response from 3rd party api for class that you need. E.g. if you need to convert it back to json you can use ApiObject.json() and that's it. It helps a lot when working with big apis to access data with just dot notation: `ApiObject.object_meta` and you will see the whole object meta you need.

Comment: Alright! I am trying this
getting :  name 'Field' is not defined error
I am new to python please help

Comment: Hey, pls have a look at answer, I update it according to example you shared below, that worked fine